# Hacer una resta con una ALU de 4-bits con inputs negativos en los bordes del rango de representación

Tags: operador

Teniendo como inputs de una ALU -6 (1010) y -8 (1000), ambos codificados usando el Complemento a 2, si quiero hacer la resta 1010 - 1000 usualmente usamos el "truco" de hacer el Complemento a 2 del segundo operando para que la expresión a - (-b) quede como a + b, pero a la hora de representar el 8 en Complemento a 2 necesitaríamos un bit extra, entonces como haríamos esta operación a mano sabiendo que la ALU la hace sin problemas? Nos basaríamos en el hecho de que para números positivos la representación tanto en Complemento a 2 como en binario natural es la misma?

Pd: Partiendo de la base de que 8 en Complemento a 2 es 01000 mientras que en binario natural es 1000 que al fin y al cabo son el mismo numero ya que a la representación en binario natural de 8 podemos añadirle tantos 0 como queramos a la izquierda del bit mas significativo.

Comment: Hola Angelixus, te saludo y te doy la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, por lo tanto te sugiero modificar tu pregunta, saludos!

Comment: Si tu rango de enteros es de 4 bits, entonces tu rango es desde `-8` a `7` y tu "resta" es: `(-6) - (-8)`, cuyo resultado es: (-14). Las ALU no operan solas, necesitan registros donde almacenar información temporalmente, sino, x86 no tendría los códigos de operación `adc`, `sbb` y compañía para realizar operaciones de este tipo. La respuesta más eficiente es utilizar un bit más, si este está disponible dentro de la misma palabra, así que sí, tienes que imaginarte que ese bit existe.